# Vosk (Kaldi) offline speech recognition in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, offline, kaldi, vosk

How to implement and use Vosk library into Unity project?
Please write steps 1,2,3...
Vosk library here - https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api

Comment: We do not support Unity in the open source version. If you have some inquiries you'd better contact us over email.

Comment: You read my thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually did it on Mac OS X.

1. Follow instructions to compile Kalid at https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install
2. Follow instruction to make C# wrapper (same)
3. Create Xcode project and make bundle.
4. Then add bundle and c# files to your unity project.

Comment: Do you have some sample?

Comment: I'm not familiar with creating Xcode bundles - could you explain step 3 further?  Thanks!